# How to make the data frame not delete the last decimal?

Tags: python, dataframe

When passing data through dataframe, remove the last decimal

```
        b= self.client.Trade.Trade_getBucketed(
        binSize=self.timeframe,
        partial=True,
        symbol='EOSZ19',
        count=1,
        reverse=True
       ).result()[0]

       print (b)

       cd = parse_dataframe(b)

       print (cd)
```

print (b) returns me:

```
[{'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 4, 0, 40, tzinfo=tzutc()), 
'symbol': 'EOSZ19', 'open': 0.0003728, 'high': 0.0003728, 'low': 
0.0003728, 'close': 0.0003728, 'trades': 0, 'volume': 0, 'vwap': None, 
'lastSize': 0, 'turnover': 0, 'homeNotional': 0.0, 'foreignNotional': 
0.0}]
```

but print (cd) returns me:

```
                        date      open      high       low     close  volume
 0 2019-10-04 00:40:00+00:00  0.000373  0.000373  0.000373  0.000373       0
```

removing the last decimal,
i need that:

```
                   date      open      high       low     close  volume
 0 2019-10-04 00:40:00+00:00  0.0003728  0.0003728  0.0003728  0.0003728   0
```

Don't take off the last decimal

the data_frame function comes from util:

```
from pandas import DatetimeIndex, merge, DataFrame, to_datetime 
from configuration import TICKER_INTERVAL_MINUTES

def parse_dataframe1(ticker: list) -> DataFrame:
"""
builds dataframe based on the given trades

:param ticker: see /trade/bucketed API
:return: DataFrame
"""

cols = ['timestamp', 'symbol', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'trades', 
'volume', 'vwap', 'lastSize', 'turnover', 'homeNotional', 
'foreignNotional']
frame = DataFrame(ticker, columns=cols)

# drop unnecessary columns
frame.drop(['symbol', 'trades', 'vwap', 'lastSize', 'turnover', 
'homeNotional', 'foreignNotional'], axis=1)

# rename timestamp column Y
frame = frame.rename(columns={'timestamp': 'date'})

# reformat date column
frame['date'] = to_datetime(frame['date'],
                            unit='ms',
                            utc=True,
                            infer_datetime_format=True)


# group by index and aggregate results to eliminate duplicate ticks
frame = frame.groupby(by='date', as_index=False, sort=True).agg({
    'open': 'first',
    'high': 'max',
    'low': 'min',
    'close': 'last',
    'volume': 'max',
})

#frame.drop(frame.tail(1).index, inplace=True)  # eliminate partial candle

return frame
```

here the data_frame function does not round in 7 decimal places

Comment: where does the parse_dataframe function come from?

Comment: excuse me, I already edited

Comment: You are almost certainly just seeing the values being rounded for display; any calculation or other direct use of the values will access them with their full original precision.  You can use `pd.set_option('precision', 7)` to change the display rounding.

Comment: I didn't know that method ... but where do I put that line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as he replied: jasonharper the correct solution to show on the console is:

```
pd.set_option('precision', 7)
```

but also if we save the variable and print again we will see the complete data